# How to convert a DVD to ISO?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, command-line, disk-utility, dvd

On Mac OSX 10.9, how do you convert a DVD into an ISO that I can use with players such as VLC.  I wish to achieve this without buying a program.

Steps I have tried:

1. Downloading Mac app Burn. It lets you select a source and save it as a DVD.
   However, when I do this, the DVD seems to be corrupt: DVDplayer can't load it properly. VLC can load it, but I only if I select the option to bypass the menus (otherwise it can't load it).
2. Using the command line

   ```
   sudo diskutil unmount /dev/disk1
   dd if=/dev/disk1 of=~/myCD.iso bs=2048 conv=sync,notrunc
   ```

   This makes the ISO, but it's the same problem as (1) above
3. Using the Command Line

   ```
   hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o Image.iso /input_path
   ```

   This gives the error message: makehybrid failed - No such file or directory
4. Using Disk Utility.

   You can use Disk utility to create an image, but it only seems to be a `.dmg` file.

Ideally, I'd like a solution that does it in one go (i.e. so I don't have to convert the `.dmg` to `.iso`) as I have 90+ discs I want to convert.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/85987/507566

Answer (score 1):

I use [MacTheRipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacTheRipper) to copy DVD and [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) convert to suitable formats for viewing on iPad etc. I do not know how it would handle copy protection.

Answer (score 1):

You can see https://superuser.com/questions/85987/mac-os-x-best-way-to-make-an-iso-from-a-cd-or-dvd for the answers.

The answer I posted there was:

1. `diskutil list`
2. `diskutil unmount /dev/disk1`
3. `dd if=/dev/disk1 of=DiscImage01.iso`
4. `diskutil eject /dev/disk1`

see the page there for more explanation.  You just have to see what the drive is for your DVD drive, such as `disk1`, `disk2`, or `disk3` by using command line 1 above, and adjust the other command lines accordingly.

Comment: See #2 in the question (the OP already tried that). `dd` will not work for your usual movie DVD.

Comment: so the OP is more concerned with copy protection, rather than how to make an ISO...

Answer (score 0):

In Disk Utility

[image]

Then rename resulted .cdr file to .iso

Should work with VLC and Windows too